# Excel Macro - Windows().Activate not taking value

Tags: excel, vba

The code that works is the following:

```
Windows("Contract Drilldown (3).xls").Activate
```

When I use :

```
 Windows(Chr(34) & ddlOpenWorkbooks.Value & Chr(34)).Activate
```

I get:

> Runtime Error '424': Object Required

---

If I use a String Variable to pass in the values i.e.:

```
Dim wbn As String
wbn = "Contract Drilldown (3).xls"
Windows(Chr(34) & wbn & Chr(34)).Activate
```

I get:

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

---

And if I use

```
wbn = ddlOpenWorkbooks.Value
Windows(Chr(34) & wbn & Chr(34)).Activate
```

I also get

> Runtime Error '424': Object Required

---

Anyone have any idea how I can pass in the *ddlOpenWorkbooks.Value* in without getting an error?

### Edit - More Info

Ok so the application looks like this:
[image]

the full code block for the Import Data Button is:

```
Public Sub Data_Import()

    Windows(ddlOpenWorkBooks.Value).Activate
    Columns("A:V").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Omni_Data.Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Omni_Data.Range("A:Z").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    Omni_Data.Range("A:Z").Font.Name = "Segoe UI"
    Omni_Data.Range("A:Z").Font.Name = "Segoe UI"
    'Setting Background Colour to white and changing font

End Sub
```

The above Sub is called on Click Event for the button.

As a test the close button has the following code:

```
Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    MsgBox (ddlOpenWorkbooks.Value)
    End

End Sub
```

Which works fine:

[image]

### Update

So we have found the problem.

As this is being called from a module it didn't know where ddlOpenWorkbooks was and where to pull that data from.

The corrected code in the Sub is:

```
Public Sub Data_Import()

    Windows(frmOmniDataManipulation.ddlOpenWorkbooks.Value).Activate
    Columns("A:V").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Omni_Data.Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Omni_Data.Range("A:Z").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    Omni_Data.Range("A:Z").Font.Name = "Segoe UI"
    Omni_Data.Range("A:Z").Font.Name = "Segoe UI"
    'Setting Background Colour to white and changing font

End Sub
```

This will allow me to call the sub.

Thanks All!

Comment: Dumb question here, but what is ddlOpenWorkbooks?

Comment: Its a drop down list. The sub behind it shows all open workbooks and I have tested it in a messagebox and it shows **Contract Drilldown (3).xls** exactly the same as above

Comment: By drop down list, you mean a combo box that you added to a VBA userform?

Comment: Yes, that's what it is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried:

```
Windows(ddlOpenWorkbooks.Value).Activate
```

The quotes are only needed if you are typing in the value. If you are passing the value in some other way the quotes are unnecessary.

UPDATE

Here are the steps I have taken, and they allow me to activate the selected window with no errors.

I created a Userform with a ComboBox named `ddlOpenWorkbooks` and 2 buttons.
[image: My UserForm]

I hardcoded the RowSource of my ComboBox for illustration purposes, but that shouldn't be the issue here.

My 1st button displays a message with the selected workbooks name from `ddlOpenWorkbooks`.

Here is the code for the button

```
Private Sub btnMessage_Click()
    MsgBox Me.ddlOpenWorkbooks.Value
End Sub
```

Here is the result

[image: Message button result]

My second button uses the selection in `ddlOpenWorkbooks` and activates that window. Here is the code.

```
Private Sub btnActivate_Click()
    Windows(Me.ddlOpenWorkbooks.Value).Activate
End Sub
```

And here is the result

[image: Activate button results]

FINAL UPDATE:

When passing the ddlOpenWorkbooks.Value to another procedure that is not a UserForm event, you'll need to include the name of your UserForm.

This is the line you'll need in your procedure to correctly get the value from the ComboBox:

```
Windows(frmOmniDataManipulation.ddlOpenWorkbooks.Value).Activate
```

Comment: Runtime Error '424': Object Required is coming up for that :(

Comment: I've edited with more detail. If you are still getting an error we'll need more details.

Comment: Added more detail above.

Comment: Ok so I have put **Windows(ddlOpenWorkbooks.Value).Activate** into the Button_Click event and that seems to work. Why? I have no idea.
It looks like the issue is when I call the Sub instead of having it run off the button directly.

Comment: So I am 90% sure the error happens when I call a Sub in the Click Event as the same error is being thrown when I tested this with the messageBox.

Comment: @Gek What is the name of your UserForm. I think that may be the issue. When you run your code in a procedure outside of the UserForm events, VBA doesn't know what `ddlOpenWorkbooks` is connected to. Changing it to `MyUserForm.ddlOpenWorkbooks` may do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If this is combobox, then I believe that

```
ddlOpenWorkbooks.List(ddlOpenWorkbooks.ListIndex)
```

will return the selected value. 
Alternatively, you can pass in the index value with

```
ddlOpenWorkbooks.List(#)
```

Comment: So I tried:
Windows(ddlOpenWorkbooks.List(ddlOpenWorkbooks.ListIndex)).Activate
And I still get error: 424 Object required

Comment: Why did you put Windows?

Comment: The value that is coming from the combobox is the name of an open workbook. 
It is passing to Windows so that the open workbook can have data copied and pasted from it. so I used Windows().Activate

Comment: `ddlOpenWorkbooks.Value` does return the selected item from the comboBox

Comment: Have you tried to use a workbook, worksheet object to push the value?

Comment: Excel.Workbooks(ddblOpenWorkbooks.List(ddlOpenWorkbooks.ListIndex)).Sheets(1).Value = SomeValue